# How to get objects in a django joined table

Tags: python, django

I have two apps each has one model:

**company** app models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   address = models.CharField()
```

**client** app models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    name = models.CharField()
```

I have a listview of my company:

```
class CompanyListView(ListView):
    model = Company
    form_class = CompanyForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CompanyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context[client_list] = ???

    return context
```

My problem is how can I pass to `context[client_list]` client list count related to a specific company?

Comment: A list view is supposed to be a list of a model... are you looking for a DetailView for a specific company?

Comment: @Sayse, is it possible to get the number of clients for each company to the context data?